# How to loop through a list of data frames and assign the numeric portion of the name as a new column value for the data frame?

Tags: r, loops, names

I have a list of data frames

```
list.files("data frame - 12345 - App", "data frame - 34567 - App", "data frame - 65849")
```

Each data frame looks like this

```
Col1|Col2 |Col3
Row1 Info1 NewInfo1
Row2 Info2 NewInfo2
```

I would like to add the number portion of the list name as the value for each row of each dataframe's new ID column. All three dataframes should like this

```
Col1|Col2 |Col3    |ID Name
Row1 Info1 NewInfo1 12345
Row2 Info2 NewInfo2 12345

Col1|Col2 |Col3    |ID Name
Row1 Info1 NewInfo1 34567
Row2 Info2 NewInfo2 34567

Col1|Col2 |Col3    |ID Name
Row1 Info1 NewInfo1 65849
Row2 Info2 NewInfo2 65849
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming such a list of data.frames

```
list(App_12345 =data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3),
     App_12345 =data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3))
$App_12345
  a b
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3

$App_12345
  a b
1 a 1
2 b 2
3 c 3
```

you can use

```
library(tidyverse)
list(App_12345 =data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3),
     App_34567 =data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "d") %>% 
  split(.$d)
$App_12345
          d a b
1 App_12345 a 1
2 App_12345 b 2
3 App_12345 c 3

$App_34567
          d a b
4 App_34567 a 1
5 App_34567 b 2
6 App_34567 c 3
```

By edding a `mutate` before the `split` you can transform as appropriate

```
mutate(d =gsub("App_", "", d))
```

As an alternative you can use `purrr`'s map function like

```
list(App_12345 =data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3),
     App_34567 =data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=1:3)) %>% 
map2(., names(.), ~mutate(.x, d = unlist(str_extract_all(.y, "[0-9]+"))))
```

Comment: I want to get rid of the App_ portion. Only include the number part as a value in the column

Comment: please see my edits on the last `map2` approach